# spark-class java no such file or derectory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am a newbie to spark / scala ... I have set up on a fully distributed cluster 
spark / scala and sbt. 
when I test and issue the command pyspark I get the following **error**:

> /home/hadoop/spark/bin/spark-class line 75
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java - no such file or
>   directory

**my bashrc contains:**

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 

hadoop-env.sh contains export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java7-openjdk-amd64/jre/ 
conf/spark-env.sh contains JAVA_HOME=usr/lib/jvm/java7-openjdk-amd64/jre 
spark-class contains 
if [ -n "${JAVA_HOME"}]; then RUNNER="${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java" else if [ "$( command -v java ) " ] then RUNNER = "java"
```

can someone assist in what I need to change to get the right path to java

Comment: Did you get spark working on a single node without clustering?

Comment: no  this is the first time setup on a fully distributed node

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue  matched all paths from .bashrc to etc to spark.conf